# Django removes my custom html attributes from option tag

Tags: python, django

I am trying to add custom data-* attributes to the option tag in a select element. I have my custom template (widget) which is used by Django, but it seems like Django removes my custom attributes. somewhere in further steps

My custom option template: 
widgets/tree_option_template.html

```
<option value="{{ widget.attrs.lft|stringformat:'s' }}"
    data-test="test"
>{{ widget.label }} - {{ widget.attrs.rght|stringformat:'s' }}</option>
```

Custom widget:

```
class MultiChoiceFilterWidget(forms.SelectMultiple):
    """
    TODO.
    Based on FilteredSelectMultiple
    """

    option_inherits_attrs = True
    option_template_name = "widgets/tree_option_template.html"
    ...
```

Usage in admin.py:

```
class UserAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = "__all__"

    read_projects = CustomTreeNodeMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=Project.objects.filter(disabled=False),
        required=False,
        widget=MultiChoiceFilterWidget(verbose_name="Projects", is_stacked=False),
    )
```

When I am changing e.g. value attribute then it changes in DOM as well but my custom attributes are not available in HTML:
[image]
As we can see there is no `data-test` attribute...

Any idea why my custom tags are not visible in HTML?
Thanks!

Comment: My guess is it's rendering the Django default widget template not your custom one. I don't think that there is any way Django could remove what is effectively just constant text if it had read your template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ANSWER/SOLUTION

I found the problem. The problem was that the `FilteredSelectMultiple` after which I inherit has attached some JS files which were manipulating my HTML attributes.

```
@property
def media(self):
    extra = "" if settings.DEBUG else ".min"
    js = [
        "vendor/jquery/jquery%s.js" % extra,
        "jquery.init.js",
        "core.js",
        "SelectBox.js",
        "SelectFilter2.js",
    ]
    ...
```

When I removed these JS files (`SelectBox.js` precisely) then my custom HTML attributes appeared.